# Dynamic jQuery pop up

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have a populated table with data from a database. Code below:

```
echo '<td style="width:5%;padding:0;">
    <div class="statusimg" id="statusimg-id'.$bookingid.'" style="position:absoulte; white-space: nowrap;" >'.$statusimg.'</div>

    <div id="booking-status" style="display:none">
        <p>Job #'.$bookingid. ' for '. $date_today.'</p>
        <p>Contact for '.$row['name'].' : <a href="tel:'. $row['phone_number'].'">'.$row['phone_number'].'</a></p>
        <div id="select_status">
            <a href="index.php?BookingID='.urlencode($row['id']).'&BookingStatus='.urlencode($booking_status_2).' " id="job_confirmed"><span>Confirm job</span><img src="icons/main/key_check_yellow.png" alt="x" width="24px" height="24px"></a>
            <a href="index.php?BookingID='.urlencode($row['id']).'&BookingStatus='.urlencode($booking_status_3).' " id="job_rogered"><span>Roger job</span><img src="icons/main/key_check_green.png" alt="x" width="24px" height="24px"></a>
        </div>
        <p>Please roger the job at least 60 minutes before the pick up time</p>
    </div>
</div>
</td>';
```

Here is my jQuery:

```
;(function($) {

     // DOM Ready
    $(function() {

        // Binding a click event
        // From jQuery v.1.7.0 use .on() instead of .bind()
        $('.statusimg').bind('click', function(e) {

            // Prevents the default action to be triggered. 
            e.preventDefault();

            // Triggering bPopup when click event is fired
            $('#booking-status').bPopup({
            });
        });

    });

})(jQuery);
```

As it is now when i click on the `statusimg` it will open booking-status for each row , but it opens them in a ascending order for each row.

And i would need a way to open only the div which corresponds to the clicked link in the row.

Comment: Sidenote: You have a typo in `style="position:absoulte;`

Answer (score 0):

Call the proper booking status using the `siblings()` method. https://api.jquery.com/siblings/

```
// Triggering bPopup when click event is fired
$(this).siblings('#booking-status').bPopup({
});
```

You can also try a more basic version.

```
$('.statusimg').click(function(e) {
  $(this).siblings('#booking-status').bPopup();
});
```

Without knowing what `bPopup();` is doing it's hard to tell why this would only work once.

Comment: I appreciate your answer and it has gotten me a bit closer to my goal but if I use your method it will open the popup only once for each row , if i try to open it again it won't popup , only after I refresh the page they will open again .

Comment: Try the simplified version.

Comment: bPopup(); would be jQuery modal popup plugin. You will find the code on this site . http://dinbror.dk/blog/bPopup/

Comment: It's not necessary to use the bPopup plugin i can use regular jQuery Modal for this if you think that the plugin is causing problems

Comment: I also tried the simplified version and it has the same results.

Comment: I switched the code to this :
   <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
And this : 
       ;(function($) {

         // DOM Ready
        $(function() {

            // Binding a click event
            // From jQuery v.1.7.0 use .on() instead of .bind()
    $('.statusimg').click(function(e) {
      $(this).siblings('#booking-status').dialog();
    });
    });

    })(jQuery);

Where can i look for errors ?